# Xamarin Forms, Android and HttpClient issue

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I've created in `Xamarin Forms` for `iOS` a `HttpClient` function to send a picture from the device to my server. The core function is

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = fName
};
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters
                   .Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("userId", UserId.ToString()));
content.Add(fileContent);

using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authenticationToken", SyncData.Token);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // more code
    }
}
```

I'm using `System.Net.Http`. I tried to use the same function for a project in Android but surprisingly it doesn't work. The problem is in the header: if I inspect `fileContent` I can see every keys but for webapi on the server `FileName` is not received.

After some logs, I changed this function adding more `client.DefaultRequestHeaders` like

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("FileName", fName);
```

Now the webapi receives `FileName` param.

Now my question is: what did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the Add method on MultipartFormDataContent that accepts a filename.

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);

...

// Use the overload Add method which accepts a file name
content.Add(fileContent, "FileName", fName);

...
```

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem or not, but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks @deckerton_9000, I resolved the problem with `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("FileName", fName);`. My issue is I can't have my `httpclient` shared between iOS and Android

Comment: Have you considered using the nuget package "Microsoft.Net.Http"? That should be compatible for both Android and iOS. Note: you will have to remove project references to System.Net.Http before adding this nuget to avoid namespace collisions and binding redirects.

Comment: If you use a Portable Class Library you can most definitely share the HttpClient code between Android and iOS.

Comment: Yes I know but in this case I have to check `Device.RuntimePlatform` and execute two different code, one for iOS and one for Android